# CSS3 Liner Gradient solid color size

Tags: html, css, gradient

I want to create liner gradient with different color with fixed width of each for for example :

```
.repeat {
width: 100%;
height: 201px;
background: linear-gradient(138deg, red 33%, red 12%, green 33%, green 67%, blue 33%, blue 10%);}
```

In this code how to fix width of red, green and blue ?

I want exactly like this with different width for all colors. [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/6d4hfjhw/1/)

Comment: Oh yeah thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvcsupjo/1/)!

CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #ff0000 33%,#00ff00 33%,#00ff00 67%,#00ff00 67%,#0000ff 67%);
```

Comment: @Madan Bhandari, this is already solid color.

Comment: means I don't want mixture of colour, I want pure red and green not mixing in between both color

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jvcsupjo/2/